# Installing Logstash on windows - An unexpected error occurred! :error=>bad URI (is not URI?)

Tags: logstash

I am trying to install the latest version of [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash) ie 5.1.1 on windows (Windows 7 Professional).

I unziped the logstash installtion file in the path : C:\Program Files\logstash-5.1.1. Now when i try to test the logstash installation with this command: 
`logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'`

But following error is shown when this command in run:
[image]

Following is mentioned on their site in the  [Installation guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/installing-logstash.html)  section: 
**Do not install Logstash into a directory path that contains colon (:) characters**

Is this the reason i am getting this error?
If yes, it seems to me that there is no way to avoid directory path with a colon on a windows environment. How do i get around this problem ?
If no, what might be the reason and how do i fix it?

Comment: It seems that Logstash has been deprecated to be used with Windows.

Comment: Ohh! But it does not seem to be mentioned anywhere on their documentation

Comment: Yeah but somehow in the complete documentation, there is no direct linked section of Installation of Logstash in Windows.
Rest other components have such sections :)

Answer (score 0):

I had posted the same question on [logstash forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/installing-latest-version-5-1-1-of-logstash-on-windows/68647)
I got a confirmation that windows 7 is not supported !!

Comment: Actually in their support matrix, they do  not mention a version of Windows.
https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#show_os

They should explicitly mention in Logstash documentation that it is no longer supported for Windows.

Comment: Yes, Ideally they should!

Comment: Logstash is supported for Windows 8 & Windows 10 :)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed on windows 10 and able to run this

logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'

Try this may be solve your issue and let me know if it does.

add environment variable let say 'LS_SETTING_DIR' and brows the path of logstash in my case it is C:\Users\mrizwan\Downloads\ELK\logstash-5.1.1\config

Comment: The question was specific to Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've solved this problem yet.
I experienced the same problem.
The answer is that there is a gap in the installation path of the logstath installation path.
So, there is a URL decoding error.
Find out where the space is located at logstash logstash igyeongno.